# Events on main queue are showing in inverse sequence

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I have a couple of functions to show a loader overlay view in UIViewController

```
 func showLoader() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let window = appDelegate.window!

        loader = LoaderView(frame: window.bounds)
        window.addSubview(loader!)

        loader?.start()
    }

    func hideLoader() {
        loader?.removeFromSuperview()
        loader?.stop()
        loader = nil
        print("hide loader")
    }
```

I also have extended UIViewController with a showAlert function:

```
 func showAlert(title title: String, message: String, cancelButton: Bool, action:((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?)  {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Localized.OK, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: action))

        if (cancelButton) {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Localized.CANCEL, style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
        }
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Then I am using it as follows:

```
self.showLoader()

DataManager.createGambler(room.id, module: module, team: team) { code, gamblerId in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.hideLoader()
        self.showAlert(title: Localized.ERROR, message: "No network connection available.", cancelButton: false, action: nil)
      }
}
```

DataManager.createGambler is an async call to a web service, running on a background queue.

**The problem is the alert view should show after the loader has hidden, and instead the opposite is happening**.

How can I make sure I keep staying on the main queue, but ensure the sequence of events: 1) hiding loader; 2) showing alert is kept?

I tried using background queues, interactive queues, adding completion block to hideLoader(), nothing seems to work? Is there a common pattern to do so?

I tried also using dispatch_sync, but this breaks the runtime leading to crash.

Here is the result, loader is still showing, alert view is already below. I want the alert to show only when loader is hidden.

[image]

Comment: Your issue isn't very clear. Does the loader show as expected and does it stay in place while the background process in `createGambler` is completed? After the background process is done, if the loader view hidden and the alert shown? Update your question with the exact sequence of events and explain how it is different from what you want.

Comment: Actually I made edits right now, I believe now it is clear, isn't it? The loader shows, but before it hides the alert view is showing already.

Comment: Your comment is much clearer that what you wrote in your question.

Comment: Add a breakPoint at loader?.removeFromSuperview(). Is this executed correctly? Perhaps loader is nil and never removed.

Comment: @stefos the loader is removed, "hide loader" is always printed. Only too late...

Comment: You need to be sure that the loader is no more visible before showing the alert.  try to embed showAlert in another dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())  to make it run in next runloop cycle.  Else you might need to use performSelector:@selector(myShowAlertMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay

Comment: @Idali, thank you, you pointed me to the right direction, for now I ended up using dispatch_after, but I hope something more synchronous can be made.